# Equality of two indefinite Cartesian products

Tags: set-theory

Following the definition of indefinite Cartesian product in [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), I wonder that how to prove the equalityof two indefinite Cartesian products.

For example, given two distinct index sets $I$ and $J$ which index the same family of nonempty sets $\{X_s\}=\{Y_t\}$. Is $\prod_{s\in I}X_s = \prod_{t\in J}Y_t$ true? If it is, how to prove it?

I come up with a particular (but may not precise) instance is: For the family of sets $\{\{1,2\}, \{3\}, ...\}$, the index set $I$ *indexes* it by $X_1=\{1,2\}$, $X_2=\{3\}$; another index set $J$ *indexes* it by $Y_1=\{3\}$, $Y_2=\{1,2\}$. The remaining indexing result is $X_k = Y_k$ for $k>2$.

(Edit: the condition $X_k =Y_k= \varnothing$ for $k>2$ is deprecated)

Then for $f_1,f_2\in\prod_{s\in I}X_s$ we have$f_1(1) = 1, f_1(2) = 3, f_2(1) = 2, f_2(2) = 3$;

for $g_1,g_2\in\prod_{t\in J}Y_t$ we have $g_1(1) = 3, g_1(2) = 1,g_2(1) = 3, g_2(2) = 2$.

By definition of [equality of functions](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section04.01.html), it seems that we cannot prove result such as $f_1=g_1$ and hence $\prod_{s\in I}X_s = \prod_{t\in J}Y_t$. But, these two indefinite Cartesian products should be equal though?

I'm not sure whether this is a wrong question/statement per se. If it is, please correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: If any of the $X_s$-s is empty, then $\prod_{s\in I} X_s=\emptyset$.

Comment: What does $\{X_s\}=\{Y_t\}$ mean? Does it mean $\{A\,\mid\, \exists s\in I, X_s=A\}=\{B\,\mid\,\exists t\in J, Y_t=B\}$, or does it mean something else?

Comment: Hi. @Sassatelli Giulio 
a.) I tried to reason $\prod_{s\in I}X_s = \varnothing$ if there exists a $X_s=\varnothing$ as follows: suppose $f\in\prod_{s\in I}X_s$ where $X_{s'}=\varnothing$ for some $s'\in I$. Then $f(s')\in X_{s'}=\varnothing$ contradicts. Is that right? 
b.) For $\{X_s\} = \{Y_t\}$, I mean that for "the same family of sets", one index set $I$ _indexes_ it and the resulting sets in the family, here, is denoted by $X_s$; another index set $J$ _indexes_ the same family and the resulting sets is denoted by $Y_t$ to prevent from confusing $I$ and $J$ to the same index thing.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I've edited the post. Hope that will be clearer.

Comment: $I=\{1\}$, $J=\{1,2\}$, $X_1=Y_1=Y_2=\{a,b\}$ are families such that $\{A\,\mid\,\exists s\in I, A=X_s\}=\{B\,\mid\,\exists t\in J, B=Y_t\}$ and $\prod_{s\in I} X_s\ne\prod_{t\in J}Y_t$.

Comment: Thanks for replying @SassatelliGiulio I think I get your point. So, even the example mentioned in the (edited) post, is $\prod_{s\in I}X_s \neq \prod_{t\in J}Y_t$?

Comment: As a matter of fact, since set-theoretically $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is the set of functions $f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ such that $f(i)\in X_i$ for all $i$, we could argue that the products are the same if and only if either $I=J$ and $\forall i\in I,\, X_i=Y_i$, or both products are empty.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for providing example and explanation. I think I got it. 